# Azure WCF Relay Permanently Faulted

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I have a number of WCF Relay resources in Azure (created in the 'Relay - PREVIEW' resource pane, rather than indirectly through a service bus namespace).

I like the newer interface as it gives me more visibility of the individual relays and their active listeners.

They are all set up in the same way but one of the relays seems to be stuck in a faulted state. There seems to be no way within the portal to 'restart' or 'reset' the relay other than deleting it and re-creating it.

Is Delete and Recreate my only option? I would not want to do this in a production environment as it adds complexity around key management.

I get the error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An AMQP error occurred (condition='amqp:internal-error'). ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpException: An AMQP error occurred (condition='amqp:internal-error').

Server stack trace: 


Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.DuplexAmqpLink.OnOperationComplete(AmqpObject link, IAsyncResult result, Boolean isOpen)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.RelayedOnewayAmqpListenerClient.AmqpRelayedConnection.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.RelayedOnewayAmqpListenerClient.GetOrCreateConnection(Uri via, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.RelayedOnewayAmqpListenerClient.Connect(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpClient.EnsureConnected(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isRetry)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpClient.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.RefcountedCommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedSocketListener.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.BufferedConnectionListener.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.SocketConnectionTransportManager.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout, TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(TimeSpan timeout, SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.SocketConnectionChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Comment: As I know  "reset" or  "restart" is not supported  currently.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this error quite a lot since this message was posted. Usually it means that Relay created using the API or portal is being connected to using an incompatible setting, such as transport security. I was most probably make that kind of mistake, without realising.